# How To Convert Oracle SQL Inner Join Statement to Lambda Expression C#

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle, model-view-controller, lambda

I have been working with Oracle SQL for a while and am currently developing an MVC application in my spare time. At the moment I stuck on an INNER JOIN lambda expression, I have no idea how to convert the SQL statement to C# lambda expression, I've had a look at other answers similar to this question but none provide the answer and a detailed description of how to convert the statement.

Code:

```
SELECT 
    t.name, t.description
FROM
    TOPICS t
INNER JOIN
    TOPIC_SUBSCRIPTIONS
        ON
    t.TOPICID = TOPIC_SUBSCRIPTIONS.TOPICID
WHERE
    TOPIC_SUBSCRIPTIONS.MEMBERID = 96;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
var q = db.Topics
          .SelectMany(t => t.TopicSubscriptions, (t, ts) => new { t, ts })
          .Where(sub => sub.ts.MemberId == 96)
          .Select(sub => new { sub.t.Name, sub.t.Description });
```

or using LINQ style

```
var q = from t in db.Topics
        from ts in topic.Subscriptions
        where ts.MemberId == 96
        select new { t.Name, t.Description };
```

Solution 2

```
var q = from t in db.Topics
        join ts in db.TopicSubscriptions on t.TopicId equals ts.TopicId
        into ij
        from tsub in ij
        where tsub.MemberId == 96
        select new { t.Name, t.Description};
```